# Multilevel parent child relation sorting using Linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, guid

I have a list and I need to sort it to this hierarchy

```
{ Id=1, ParentId = null, Name = "Item1", Type="0"}
   { Id=2, ParentId = 1, Name = "ItemChild1", Type="1"}
   { Id=3, ParentId = 1, Name = "ItemChild2", Type="1"}
        { Id=4, ParentId = 3, Name = "ItemGrandChild1", Type="2"}
   { Id=5, **ParentId = 1**, Name = "ItemGrandChild2", Type="2"}

{ Id=6, ParentId = null, Name = "Item7", Type="0"}
...
```

Unlike normal parent child relationships, here

Items of Type2 can be child of either Type1 or Type0

All the Id's are guids

I have seen may stack answers on child parent sorting using Linq. But my case is different.
Any elegant way using Linq ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup to find fast the children and project them to the parent collection. As far as i see it does not depend at all if your children have different types as long as they know which element is their parent.

```
public class TreeItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TreeItem> Children { get; set; }

    public void PrintAllChildren()
    { 
        this.PrintAllChildren(0);
    }

    private void PrintAllChildren(int indent)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{1}Item id: {0}", this.Id, string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat<int>(0, indent).Select(i => " ")));
        if (this.Children != null)
            foreach (var item in this.Children)
                item.PrintAllChildren(indent + 1);
    }
}

public static class TreeItemExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeItem> GetAsTree(this IEnumerable<TreeItem> data)
    {
        var lookup = data.ToLookup(i => i.ParentId);
        return lookup[null].Select(i => {
            i.FillChildren(lookup);
            return i;
        });
    }
    private static TreeItem FillChildren(this TreeItem item, ILookup<int?, TreeItem> lookup)
    {
        item.Children = lookup[item.Id].Select(i => i.FillChildren(lookup));
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would give up trying to sort this with either linq or sql. Abstractions can be helpful, but in a complex case like this they will just get in your way.

You will save a lot of time if you just write your own sorter.

```
class MyCompare : IComparer<MyObject>
{
  public int Compare(x1, x2)
  {
      if (x1.parent == parent1 && x2.parent == parent2)
        return 1;
      if (x1.parent == x2.parent)
        return 0;
      //ect 
  }
}
List<MyObject> list = GetWeirdObjects();
list.Sort(new MyCompare());
```